# Are the 2 cameras of the iPhone 4S of the same quality?

Tags: iphone

I wonder if the 2 cameras inside an iphone 4S are of the same type?

Comment: Is there some reason why you felt they were the same? (Or are you referring to the chip themselves, since it's clear that the lens on the rear is seriously more engineered than the front facing camera.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as noted in [Apple's specifications](http://www.apple.com/iphone/iphone-4s/specs.html), the front camera is VGA (640x480), whereas the rear camera does 5 MP stills and 1080p video. This is confirmed in [iFixit's teardown](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/iPhone+4+Teardown/3130/1) of the 4S.